# has any language ever lost articles?

Tags: linguistic-typology, language-change, articles

many languages have articles (words translating as "a" and "the"); at the same time many languages lack articles. are there any known cases of a language having articles but losing them through language change?

Comment: a question about this site; if someone suggests a question that covers the same ground as mine but my question is more general; what should I do? am still figuring out parts of this site

Comment: Essentially: Do nothing right now, let the site's self-moderation or a moderator decide it and accept the result of that decision. — BTW, I don't think that your question is really more general, as one example is sufficient to answer it. The linked question provides this example with a thorough discussion.

Comment: When you are interested in *other* examples, you can ask a new question (do not change this one!) along the lines: Are there other examples than Eastern Aramaic for the loss of a definite article in language evolution? And explicitly cite that question on Eastern Aramaic in the body of this new question.

Comment: Gottcha; I will do exactly that